# electron . is rendering a blank screen

Tags: electron

After a successful build last week I came back to make some changes to a project and `electron .` is now rendering a white screen.

I looks like the react app is not being loaded into the electron app. I'm also having the same issue after running an electron build.

No actual changes have been made to the codebase so maybe it's an module incompatibility.

### package.json

```
"dependencies": {
   "array-shuffle": "^1.0.1",
   "electron-is-dev": "^0.3.0",
   "enzyme": "^2.9.1",
   "history": "^4.7.2",
   "node-sass-chokidar": "^0.0.3",
   "npm-run-all": "^4.0.2",
   "opn": "^5.3.0",
   "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
   "react": "^15.6.1",
   "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
   "react-markdown": "^3.3.0",
   "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
   "react-router": "^4.2.0",
   "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.6",
   "react-scripts": "^1.0.10",
   "react-showdown": "^1.6.0",
   "react-test-renderer": "^15.6.1",
   "react-transition-group": "^2.2.1",
   "react-unity-webgl": "^6.5.0",
   "redux": "^3.7.2",
   "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.2",
   "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
   "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
   "ajv": "^6.5.2",
   "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
   "cz-conventional-changelog": "^2.0.0",
   "electron": "2.0.3",
   "electron-builder": "^20.24.2",
   "env-cmd": "^8.0.2",
   "eslint": "^4.19.1",
   "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
   "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.13.0",
   "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.1",
   "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.7.0",
   "jest-cli": "^20.0.4",
   "wait-on": "^2.1.0"
 },
 "scripts": {
   "build": "npm run build-css && react-scripts build",
   "build:dev": "PUBLIC_URL=/ap npm run build",
   "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/",
   "electron-dev": "concurrently \"BROWSER=none npm start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\"",
   "electron-pack": "build --linux --mac --em.main=build/electron.js",
   "electron-pack-win": "env-cmd .env.deploy electron-builder --win",
   "electron-pack-windir": "build --win --dir --em.main=build/electron.js",
   "preelectron-pack": "npm run build",
   "commitmsg": "validate-commit-msg",
   "eject": "react-scripts eject",
   "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
   "start-js": "react-scripts start",
   "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
   "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive"
 },
```

### project structure

```
├── assets
├── build
|  ├── assets
|  |  ├── documents
|  |  ├── executables
|  |  ├── images
|  |  ├── ui
|  |  └── videos
|  └── static
|     ├── css
|     ├── js
|     └── media
├── dist
|  └── win-unpacked
|     ├── locales
|     └── resources
├── public
|  └── assets
|  |  ├── documents
|  |  ├── executables
|  |  ├── images
|  |  ├── ui
|  |  └── videos
└── src
|  ├── actions
|  ├── assets
|  |  ├── fonts
|  |  ├── images
|  |  └── styles
|  ├── components
|  |  ├── App
...
|  ├── data
|  ├── helpers
|  └── reducers
```

Comment: pls post the project structure

Comment: Just added the project structure

Comment: where is your main.js file?

Comment: in /public and it gets pulled into the /build when running the React build script

Comment: okay so you have to add that in package.json. "main": "main.js"(whatever the path is)

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem @alanionita ?

Comment: @vaibhavS it's been a while but actually had this issue a few times afterwards. It always seemed to boil down to a mismatch.

Comment: @vaibhavS ^ a modules mismatch. Are you seeing this in newer versions of React and Electron?

Comment: @alanionita I'm not sure if my problem is related, but I am having trouble with `extraResources` .asar when using electron-packager as it is unable to find my assets after I package the app.